# Setting a dynamic paste range within a nested loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that creates a bunch of new sheets, names them, and then loops through them searching a dataset for the name of the sheet and transposing data rows with a value matching the name of the sheet.

I've gotten it to work transposing each row to the next column to the right, but for printing purposes, I'd like it to move to the bottom of the last pasted cell, skip a row (or better yet, insert a page break), and then paste the next one.

Something about the way I've tried to tell it to count the rows, move down, and then start again, isn't working. It appears to be pasting multiple times over previously pasted data.

I've tried several different ways of counting the rows and adding a row, or inserting a page break, but I can't get it working. I thought maybe I needed to move the rowcount function out of the IF statement, but that didn't work either.

```vb
Sub Franchise_Data4()
'searches Raw Data sheet for the Franchise ID associated with each sheet name; then transposes each relevant row onto the associated sheet'

Dim Scol As Range, Cell As Object, rawdata As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, lc As Long, rowcountA As Integer, startR As Integer, labels As Range

Set rawdata = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
Set Scol = rawdata.Range("$C$2:$C$2000") 'Franchise ID column on Raw Data sheet'
Set labels = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:AZ1")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Raw Data" And ws.Name <> "Pivot" Then
            With ws 'cycles through all of the sheets with Franchise ID's as the name
            startR = 0

                For Each Cell In Scol 'should scan the C column on the Raw Data sheet'
                    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then Exit For

                    If Cell.Value = ws.Name Then 'checks for cells that contain the same Franchise ID as the current sheet in the cycle'
                    Cell.EntireRow.Copy
                    ws.Cells(startR + 1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
                    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

                    labels.Copy
                    ws.Cells(startR + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
                    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

                    End If
                    rowcountA = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    startR = rowcountA + 1
                Next
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

It appears to paste the first data set correctly, then move down 1 row (instead of the rowcount+1) and paste again. Then I guess it either stops, or it continues pasting the rest in the same spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the `Worksheet` that the `Cells` are on.

```
rowcountA = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

There's an implicit `ActiveSheet` here, not a reference to `ws` as you would want. You already have a `With ws...End With` so change this line to:

```
rowcountA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Note that there are other instances where you are "repeating" the `ws` instead of fully taking advantage of the `With ws...End With`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen. A couple follow-up questions: 1) Is the rowcountA bit in the right place to make sure it tells the next selection to paste under the previous one? 2) Are you saying that pasting an entire row in col B is overwriting data, or screwing up the rowcount? I need to transpose a fixed range (A1:AZ1) in col A (these are the data labels), and then transpose rows of data with matching criteria next to it in col B, repeating for however many matches there are.

Comment: Ideally, the # of rows would be dynamic, with a page break inserted at the end, and then the next group pasted below that, but it's also acceptable to fix the range at 52 columns on the source sheet (so 52 rows on the destination sheet) and just deal with the wasted space

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Sorry, missed the `Transpose` portion.